# How does tile of universal app work on windows 10?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm trying to make tile of universal app on windows 8.1 and 10, i have use template [TileSquare310x310ImageAndText01](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileSquare310x310ImageAndText01) . On windows 8.1, my tile works like template which i found on internet but on windows 10, it doesn't work like that.I have tried to find information about this on internet but i get nothing. Could you give me some information about this.

I took this image on start screen of windows 8.1

[image]

And this is what i took on windows 10

[image]

Comment: Did you tried instead of `<visual version="2">` to `<visual version="3">`

Comment: Hi Mohit Shrivastava, I thinks that this template i used requires the visual element to declare version="2".

Answer (score 0):

To remove the "gray" overlay, set attribute "hint-overlay" of the  to "0", set "version" to "3".

Try [Notification Extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/08/20/introducing-notificationsextensions-for-windows-10.aspx) to get the right layout.